# Access all BIOS settings

Tags: bios

I have an HP ProBook 430 G2 Notebook, and I want to make it automatically start at a specific time.

Following [these instructions](http://lifehacker.com/5831504/how-can-i-start-and-shut-down-my-computer-automatically-every-morning) I have found the option I am looking for in the BIOS, but like lots of other options, the contents of the menu are grayed out and I can't edit them.

I am logged in as an administrator.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of what does the BIOS menu look like?

Comment: While in the bios try Ctrl+A, see if it gets the advanced access.

Comment: That did nothing

Comment: thanx for the edit @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like

Comment: @Hazzdood I've inlined the image but that is almost unreadable. Take a better picture please

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like can you put this inline: http://s19.postimg.org/v0nbjge1f/IMG_2278.jpg

Comment: Have you set a password for the admin account?

Comment: the option to set one is greyed. I just use my normal windows account password @Jonno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't verify this as I don't have an HP laptop, but there are several sources online with an answer to this, stating you need to **login as a guest**, rather than using your Windows login. This, apparently, **allows you to change these options, or at the very least set an admin password** to then login as an admin. Seems a bit backwards, but hopefully is the resolution for you.

[Source 1](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/All-BIOS-options-are-disabled-grayed-out/td-p/2169837)

[Source 2](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/BIOS-settings-grayed-out-Login-To-BIOS-as-Administrator/td-p/1060073)

[Source 3](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Can-t-change-BIOS-settings-after-HP-ProtectTools-has-been/td-p/909575)